# Responsive tables mobile / desktop

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive table that contains three elements in the following distribution:

[![This is how it looks on desktop][1]][1]

However, I need to adapt this to distribution to look like this on mobile:

[![How should this look on mobile][2]][2]

Here my code so far:

```html
 <tr>
            <td>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper"><tr><td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
 
  <tr>
   <td style="background: #ffffff; padding: 0px 50px 20px 50px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <!-- LIST ITEM -->
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 60px; height: auto; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; " valign="middle" width="121">
        <img alt="" border="0" class="verticalAlignTop" height="121" src="https://i0.wp.com/www.un.org/pga/73/wp-content/uploads/sites/53/2018/09/Dummy-image-1.jpg?ssl=1" style="width: 121px; height: 121px;" valign="middle" width="121"></td><td style="vertical-align: top; padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px; text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-weight: 400; display: block" valign="top">
        <h3 style="font-size: 18px; line-height: 25px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; font-weight: 700; color: #333333;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</h3></td> <td style="vertical-align: bottom; padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px; text-align: left; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-weight: 400; display: inline-block" valign="bottom">
          <p style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum </p></td> </tr>
       </table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
```

If anyone have any idea it will be really appreciated it!

Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC3Q7.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGqV9.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to css grid system
See the example:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score -1):

Tables don't work that way. Have you tried [grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)